# Installing .NET Framework 4.5.2 for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-update, .net-framework

I've been trying to install .NET Framework 4.5.2 in my laptop (Windows 8 OS) so I can install Visual Studio Community 2015.

I've tried installing it through Windows update but it just fails to install and I've also tried the offline installer but it just gives me the following:

[image: offlineinstaller]

I opened the log file:

[image: logerror]

How do I fix this? I really need to install the Visual Studio Community 2015.